# Docker : RUN cd ... does not work as expected

Tags: docker

The following Dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:12.10
RUN mkdir tmp123
RUN cd tmp123
RUN pwd
```

has the output :

```
Uploading context 10240 bytes
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:12.10
 ---> b750fe79269d
Step 2 : RUN mkdir tmp123
 ---> Running in d2afac8a11b0
 ---> 51e2bbbb5513
Step 3 : RUN cd tmp123
 ---> Running in 4762147b207c
 ---> 644801121b92
Step 4 : RUN pwd
 ---> Running in 3ed1c0f1049d
/
 ---> eee62a068585
```

when built (docker build command)

it appears that RUN cd tmp123 has no effect

why ?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

It is actually expected.

A dockerfile is nothing more but a wrapper on docker run + docker commit.

```
FROM ubuntu:12.10
RUN mkdir tmp123
RUN cd tmp123
RUN pwd
```

Is the same thing as doing:

```
CID=$(docker run ubuntu:12.10 mkdir tmp123); ID=$(docker commit $CID)
CID=$(docker run $ID cd tmp123); ID=$(docker commit $CID)
CID=$(docker run $ID pwd); ID=$(docker commit $CID)
```

Each time you RUN, you spawn a new container and therefore the pwd is '/'.

If you feel like it, you can open an issue on github in order to add a CHDIR instruction to Dockerfile.

Comment: The command WORKDIR serves this purpose: http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#workdir

Comment: It would also be neat if `docker build` could throw a warning of some kind when people make this mistake, I just lost a lot of time to this -_-

Comment: @creack Thanks for the clear explanation - I tried running the docker run commands - they didn't return the CID in my case. Hence I had to use - `docker run ubuntu:latest mkdir tmp123 && CID=$(docker ps --latest --quiet) && ID=$(docker commit $CID ubuntu:test1)  `

Comment: can `WORKDIR ` run inside `RUN` cmd?

Comment: It works when put n same RUN command 'RUN cd path && pwd'

Answer (score 30):

Maybe you can try this; I am not sure and I can't try it. If it does not work, I hope you don't downvote.

Just:

```
RUN 'cd tmp123 ; pwd'
```

Instead of

```
RUN cd tmp123
RUN pwd
```

Comment: You need to put single or double quotes around the commands, otherwise the `pwd` will be outside the container. `RUN 'cd tmp123;pwd'`

Comment: I would do `RUN cd tmp123 && pwd` :)

Comment: `/bin/sh: 1: cd slurm ; pwd: not found`