# Docker: What is the default WORKDIR in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, workdir

We can use [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) to set a directory as work directory in `Dockerfile`, but what's the default value if we don't set?

Comment: Just execute a single-line Dockerfile with `RUN pwd`

Answer (score 93):

[docker workdir](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#workdir)

says it is `/`, so the root directory

Answer (score 65):

The default is indeed `/` as stated elsewhere. It is worth mentioning, though, that you will almost never be running from an empty docker image (`FROM scratch`), so the `WORKDIR` is likely set by the base image you're using.

For instance, https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/master/Dockerfile-alpine.template has `WORKDIR $CATALINA_HOME`, and https://github.com/dockerfile/ubuntu/blob/master/Dockerfile has `WORKDIR /root`. (https://hub.docker.com/r/base/archlinux/~/dockerfile/ does not use `WORKDIR` however.)

It is best, therefore, to set your own `WORKDIR` explicitly.

Answer (score 26):

The default working directory for running binaries within a container is the root directory (`/`), but the developer can set a different directory with the Dockerfile WORKDIR command. The operator can override this with:

```
-w="": Working directory inside the container
```

Here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#workdir

Answer (score 5):

As there is are no users but a root in a just born docker or a container strictly speaking. So, for every change there will be a commit for that container as this [guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17892255/4014399) said. Hence the pwd of that or as you asked the WORKDIR is `/`  root by default and every time you exec a `/bin/bash` like this:

`$docker exec -i -t 53f784fwer54 /bin/bash`

on a running container it will put you here `/` in the root dir.

Comment: Your answer is not only off-topic, it's just plain wrong. First, the question is: What is the default WORKDIR of an IMAGE if one is not set explicitly in the Dockerfile. Your answer saying that the default workdir of a new CONTAINER is `/` is incorrect and irrelevant. The default workdir of a new container is the same as the default workdir of the image. For instance, I just ran `docker exec -ti <my_app> /bin/bash;` then in the new bash process, `pwd`, and I see that the working directory is `/app`.