# Default location of container image

Tags: docker

I am trying to run the Docker command below:

```
docker run -it --net container:some-mongo nicolaka/netshoot tcpdump -qns 0 -X -r mypcap.pcap
```

The DOS error I get is: "mypcap.pcap: No such file or directory".  If I run this command then it works as expected:

```
docker run -it --net container:some-mongo nicolaka/netshoot tcpdump
```

What path location is Docker looking at for: mypcap.pcap ?

I have tried `docker inspect some-mongo`, however this just tells me relative paths.

I have also tried Googling this, however my research tells me that Docker can store images and containers in lots of different places.

How can I find the path that tcpdump is looking at?

It is a Linux container on a Windows host.

Answer (score 0):

Looking path location is specified by WORKDIR.
The default is `/`.
WORKDIR is specified in Dockerfile.

### documents

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#workdir)
- [What's the default WORKDIR in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782488/whats-the-default-workdir-in-docker)

### Supplement

If `mypcap.pcap` exists in the `some-mongo` container, it will be as follows.

```
# e.g. Prerequisites /tmp/mypcap.pcap exists in some-mongo
# copy to host machine.
docker cp some-mongo:/tmp/mypcap.pcap C:¥tmp¥mypcap.pcap 
# mount mypcap.pcap directory.
docker run -it -v C:¥tmp:/opt/tcpdump nicolaka/netshoot tcpdump -qns 0 -X -r /opt/tcpdump/mypcap.pcap
```

Comment: There is no WORKDIR defined in the Dockerfile: https://hub.docker.com/r/nicolaka/netshoot/dockerfile

Comment: "tcpdump: truncated dump file; tried to read 4 file header bytes, only got 0"

Comment: If it is no specification on the alpine side too , it will default to `/` .

Comment: I think that error is probably a problem with the mypcap.pcap file .

Comment: Maybe you need root Privilege to run Tcpdump.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ns-3-users/KRKzuCeRZxY.

In that case, use the privileged option..
e.g. `docker run -it --privileged -v C:¥tmp:/opt/tcpdump nicolaka/netshoot tcpdump -qns 0 -X -r /opt/tcpdump/mypcap.pcap`

Comment: `/opt/tcpdump` is any place. You can specify the location.
You should read this [document](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Comment: Thanks again.  It would help to see some step by step instructions starting with the creation of the file here: docker exec -it some-mongo /bin/bash

Answer (score 0):

If you run the command that way it will look for it in the "/". But you can give it any path you want by specifying the full path.

You should also map the mpcap file:

```
docker run -it --net container:some-mongo \
-v $(pwd)/mypcap.pcap:/mypcap.pcap \
nicolaka/netshoot \
tcpdump -qns 0 -X -r mypcap.pcap
```

or on 1 line:

```
docker run -it --net container:some-mongo -v $(pwd)/mypcap.pcap:/mypcap.pcap nicolaka/netshoot tcpdump -qns 0 -X -r mypcap.pcap
```

This maps it from the local directory.

Comment: docker: Error response from daemon: create $(pwd)/mypcap.pcap: "$(pwd)/mypcap.pcap" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.

Comment: This only means you are running on Windows. This is the correct way to do it. I don't know the correct way to get the current working directory in Windows. You should not pass absolute paths and especially not post them here.

Comment: Thanks again.  It would help to see some step by step instructions starting with the creation of the file here: docker exec -it some-mongo /bin/bash.

Comment: It would indeed but that is not part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your exact question, we can see when inspecting your image (`docker inspect nicolaka/netshoot:latest`) that there is no `WorkingDir` defined. In this case, the default dir is `/` (see [What's the default WORKDIR in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782488/whats-the-default-workdir-in-docker)). But you have to understand that this is the directory **inside the running container**, not the directory *on your host machine*.

Note that the command you used (i.e. `docker inspect some-mongo`) is not inspecting your actual image/container but the one your have chosen as a base to attach your network.

If I understand well, your file is in your current dir on your local command line. To do what you want, you need to make the `mypcap.pcap` file available to your container.

There are basically 2 ways to do this depending on your requirements.

## Build an extended image

The idea is to extend your base image by copying the file inside it. You will need a Dockerfile for that

```
FROM nicolaka/netshoot:latest
COPY mypcap.pcap .
```

Then build the image

```sh
docker build . -t myextendedimage:mytag
```

And launch a container based on the new image

```sh
docker run -it --net container:some-mongo myextendedimage:mytag tcpdump -qns 0 -X -r mypcap.pcap
```

## Bind mount your file in your container

In your situation this would probably be my preferred option. Assuming that your pcap file is located in `C:\tmp\mypcap.pcap`

```sh
docker run -it --net container:some-mongo -v C:\tmp\mypcap.pcap:/mypcap.pcap nicolaka/netshoot tcpdump -qns 0 -X -r mypcap.pcap
```

Note that you can mount this file in the image anywhere you like:

```sh
docker run -it --net container:some-mongo -v C:\tmp\mypcap.pcap:/my/random/dir/mypcap.pcap nicolaka/netshoot tcpdump -qns 0 -X -r mypcap.pcap
```

Comment: What is <absolute path>? what is myfiles? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  It would help to see some step by step instructions starting with the creation of the file here: docker exec -it some-mongo /bin/bash

Comment: @w0051977 absolute  path is absolute path (X:/path/to/file in your case under windows). Regarding the rest, If you are talking about creating the file interactively inside the container under a bash shell, I would never recommend to do that as the file will be lost everytime you recycle the container.

Comment: what is myfiles? I believe the file is in the root directory.

Comment: `myfiles` is a random name to bindmount in your container. You can choose whatever you want or even mount directly in the root directory (`-v <absolutepath>\mypcap.pcap:/mypcap.pcap`). Please read the doc about [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) for further details.

Comment: Can you run your second command from your answer? I see an error.  My research is telling me that it should create the file on the localhost and in the container.  Is that right? Thanks again.

Comment: Where is your `mypcap.pcap` file located exactly ? Be precise. Local windows machine or somewhere else ? What is the absolute path to this file on the given device ?

Comment: C:\tmp\mypcap.pcap (this is the windows localhost with docker for windows installed).  The container is a linux container.  This is a learning exercise

Comment: `docker run -it --net container:some-mongo -v C:\tmp\mypcap.pcap:/mypcap.pcap nicolaka/netshoot tcpdump -qns 0 -X -r mypcap.pcap`

Comment: Thanks.  I will try this shortly.  Will this create the .ncap in the net shoot container (rather than the some-mongo container)? I assume that the file does not have to exist in neither the container nor the localhost? I.e. your command will create the files?

Comment: You have all that is needed to try and read more doc if needed.