# I have tried and really need some help in understanding why docker file wont run this script

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I am trying, as part of an exercise, to create an image and run a simple bash script. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN chmod 700 .

#Create container to store file in
RUN mkdir doc-conatiner
 
# source then the destination of container in docker if I have one
COPY . /functionfibonnaci/doc-conatiner

#when conatiner starts what is the executable
CMD ["bash", "functionfibonnaci.sh"]
```

when I run docker run:

````
bash: functionfibonnaci.sh: No such file or directory```

No such file or direcotry

I have been at this for two days and just cant get this to work- so answers will be appreiacted.
````

Comment: May I add there are no issues in building the image- just running the thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @KapilKhandelwal indicates in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72784928), you're having trouble because the `bash functionfibonnaci.sh` command is looking for the script in the current directory, but you've never changed directories, so you're in the container filesystem's root directory.

I'd suggest updating this in a couple of ways:

- On your host system, outside of Docker, make sure that the script starts with a "shebang" line; the very first line, starting at the very first character, should be `#!/bin/sh` (or if you have bash-specific extensions and can't remove them, `#!/bin/bash`, but try to stick to POSIX shell syntax if you can).
- On your host system, outside of Docker, make sure the script is executable; `chmod +x functionfibonnaci.sh`.  With this and the previous step, you'll be able to just run `./functionfibonnaci.sh` without explicitly mentioning the shell.
- In the Dockerfile, change `WORKDIR` to some directory early.  Often a short directory name like `/app` works well.
- You don't need to `RUN mkdir` the `WORKDIR` directory or directories you `COPY` into; Docker creates them for you.
- When you `COPY` content into the Dockerfile, the right-hand side can be a relative path like `.`, relative to the current `WORKDIR`, so you don't need to repeat the directory name.
- In your `CMD` you can also specify the script location relative to the current directory.

These updates will get you:

```bash
FROM ubuntu

# do not need to mkdir this directory first
WORKDIR /app # or /functionfibonnaci/doc-conatiner if you prefer

# copy the entire build-context directory into the current workdir
COPY . .

# the command does not need to explicitly name the interpreter
# (assuming the script has a "shebang" line and is executable)
CMD ["./functionfibonnaci.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it is clear that `functionfibonnaci.sh` is not found.

Update the CMD command in the Dockerfile to this:

```
CMD ["bash", "/functionfibonnaci/doc-conatiner/functionfibonnaci.sh"]
```

**Note:** This will work if the `functionfibonnaci.sh` file is in the same directory where the Dockerfile is present on the host machine. If it is present in a different directory, feel free to update the path of the file in the CMD accordingly.

**TL;DR**

Let's look closely what you are trying to do. The first two lines of the Dockerfile are self-explainatory.
In the third command, you are creating a directory with the intention to copy your script files. Sounds good so far!!!

The fourth line of the Dockerfile is what created a mess IMO. You are actually copying all the files from host to the directory `/functionfibonnaci/doc-conatiner`. But wait, you were supposed to copy those file inside the `doc-conatiner` directory that you created earlier.. right?

Now in the last line of the Dockerfile, you are trying to run the bash script `functionfibonnaci.sh`. But now, since the [default WORKDIR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37782488/8405123) is `/` by default, it will search for the `functionfibonnaci.sh` file inside the `/` directory. This file is actually present inside the `/functionfibonnaci/doc-conatiner` directory.

Hence, you are facing this issue.

Comment: Thanks- it all makes sense now.  I managed to get it to work by taking your advice!