# What is the point of WORKDIR on Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm learning Docker. For many times I've seen that `Dockerfile` has `WORKDIR` command:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ “npm”, “start” ]
```

Can't I just omit `WORKDIR` and `Copy` and just have my `Dockerfile` at the root of my project? What are the downsides of using this approach?

Comment: At build time you change directory by `WORKDIR`

Comment: @Ultraviolet could you please explain this. I'm not quite getting the point

Comment: would `RUN mkdir -p ~/new_folder` work? how do I use the working dir name to run docker commands in the docker file now?

Answer (score 326, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir):

> The WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD,
> ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the
> Dockerfile. If the WORKDIR doesn’t exist, it will be created even if it’s not used in any subsequent Dockerfile instruction.

Also, in the [Docker best practices](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#workdir) it recommends you to use it:

> ... you should use WORKDIR instead of proliferating instructions like
> RUN cd … && do-something, which are hard to read, troubleshoot, and
> maintain.

I would suggest to keep it.

I think you can refactor your Dockerfile to something like:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: @MarioGil Please take a look into [the COPY documentation.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

Comment: When I use ``FROM ubuntu as builder`` and then the successive image use ``COPY``, does it "know" I used WORKDIR in the "builder" image or I have to assume not (and use an absolute path) ?

Comment: According to the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) I would say that it keeps the `WORKDIR` value because is an instruction ran in the Dockerfile before you run the `COPY` one

Comment: @Alex75 it does not. I have just tried it and it's not working. I'm still troubleshooting the issue. Also, the examples in the docs show code being copied from the root folder; I'll stick with absolute paths for now

Comment: would `RUN mkdir -p ~/new_folder` work? how do I use the working dir name to run docker commands in the docker file now?

Comment: @charlie-parker you should use just WORKDIR your_path,  no RUN mkdir ...  command

Answer (score 122):

You dont have to

`RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app`

This will be created automatically when you specifiy your `WORKDIR`

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ “npm”, “start” ]
```

Comment: However, sometimes RUN mkdir is needed because WORKDIR doesn’t respect USER when creating directories - https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20295

Comment: I like the fact that you specified WORKDIR will create the folder automatically.

Answer (score 86):

You can think of `WORKDIR` like a `cd` inside the container (it affects commands that come later in the Dockerfile, like the `RUN` command). If you removed `WORKDIR` in your example above, `RUN npm install` wouldn't work because you would not be in the `/usr/src/app` directory inside your container.

I don't see how this would be related to where you put your Dockerfile (since your Dockerfile location on the host machine has nothing to do with the pwd inside the container). You can put the Dockerfile wherever you'd like in your project. However, the first argument to `COPY` is a relative path, so if you move your Dockerfile you may need to update those `COPY` commands.

Comment: If `WORKDIR` adds like `cd`,  won't  the two `COPY` in the original example have the same source and destination?

Comment: No. `WORKDIR` affects the working directory _inside the container_. In the original example, the first `COPY` copies from `package.json` _on the host_ (relative path to the Dockerfile) to `/usr/src/app/package.json` _in the container_. In fact, the `WORKDIR` has no impact on that particular command because the destination (inside the container) is not using a relative path (the path starts with `/`).

Comment: @mkasberg If `WORKDIR` acts like a `cd`. So does the 2 snippets below equivalent?

`WORKDIR /usr/src/app`
`COPY package.json /usr/src/app/`
and

`WORKDIR /usr/src/app`
`COPY package.json .`

Thanks

Comment: Yes, those are equivalent.

Comment: I feel like Derek Zoolander saying, "*IN* the [Docker Container]!" O.o I get it now. Not relevant to the dev environment... only relevant to the runtime inside the Docker container. Got it. But... can it just be the root (i.e. "/")?

Comment: Yes, you can do `WORKDIR /` and your workdir will be the root. However, it's very unusual to add non-standard folders in the root directory and it would also be a bit unusual to make that your workdir. So typically, you'd want to do use something like `/app`, `/root/app`, `/opt/app`, or `/usr/src/app` like the above example and copy your apps files to that location in the container and then build and run your app from there (in the container). So `WORKDIR /` is allowed but uncommon.

Comment: is the work directory present inside the container itself? or is it created on the OS? e.g if my docker file path is /path/to/dockerfile , will the work directory path be /path/to/dockerfile/usr/src/app ? or will it be simply /usr/src/app?

Comment: Simply `/usr/src/app`. It's a path inside the container.

Comment: To be clear, WORKDIR affects the working directory in the (current) build container, which is not necessarily the same as the (final) container built by the image created by the Dockerfile.

Comment: what is the point of adding this extra dir? If it is only inside the container is it not just excess dirs?

Answer (score 11):

Before applying WORKDIR. Here the WORKDIR is at the wrong place and is not used wisely.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2
COPY --from=build-env /publish /publish
WORKDIR /publish
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/publish/api.dll"]
```

We corrected the above code to put WORKDIR at the right location and optimised the following statements by removing `/Publish`

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2
WORKDIR /publish
COPY --from=build-env /publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "api.dll"]
```

So it acts like a `cd` and sets the tone for the upcoming statements.

Comment: You should not have the slash infront of api.dll as that would path it to the root of the container

Answer (score 7):

The answer by @juanlumn is great, but I wanted to add one more (important) thing.

In regular command line, if you `cd` somewhere, it stays there until you change it. However, in a Dockerfile, each `RUN` command starts back at the root directory! That's a [gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17892255/5783745) for docker newbies, and something to be aware of.

So not only does `WORKDIR` make a more obvious visual cue to someone reading your code, but it also keeps the working directory for more than just the one RUN command.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of using vars as the target directory name for `WORKDIR` - doing that appears to result in a "cannot normalize nothing" fatal error. IMO, it's also worth pointing out that `WORKDIR` behaves in the same way as `mkdir -p <path>` i.e. all elements of the path are created if they don't exist already.

UPDATE:
I encountered the variable related problem (mentioned above) whilst running a multi-stage build - it now appears that using a variable is fine - if it (the variable) is "in scope" e.g. in the following, the 2nd `WORKDIR` reference fails ...

```
FROM <some image>
ENV varname varval
WORKDIR $varname

FROM <some other image>
WORKDIR $varname
```

whereas, it succeeds in this ...

```
FROM <some image>
ENV varname varval
WORKDIR $varname

FROM <some other image>
ENV varname varval
WORKDIR $varname
```

.oO(*Maybe it's in the docs & I've missed it*)

Comment: If you put your `ENV` values before the first `FROM`, I believe they are in scope for all `FROM` sections.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful where you set `WORKDIR` because it can affect the continuous integration flow. For example, setting it to `/home/circleci/project` will cause error something like `.ssh` or whatever is the remote circleci is doing at setup time.