# Can't get Docker container to run on localhosts it says "connection reset"?

Tags: docker, go

Can't get Docker container to run on localhosts it says "connection reset" when going to localhost:8080. 
Here is what I do know so bear with me:

1. The code runs locally when I run it and I am able to see the http://localhost:8080 page
2. The Docker build command completes with no errors

Error when curling the server:

> curl -X GET http://localhost:8080
>   curl: (52) Empty reply from server

`docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name goserver -it goserver`

The Dockerfile:

```
 FROM golang:1.9.2
 ENV SRC_DIR=/go/src/
 ENV GOBIN=/go/bin

 WORKDIR $GOBIN

 # Add the source code:
 ADD . $SRC_DIR

 RUN cd /go/src/;

 RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux;

 CMD ["go","run","main.go"]


 #ENTRYPOINT ["./main"]

 EXPOSE 8080
```

Here is the go code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>This is the homepage. Try /hello and /hello/Sammy\n</h1>")
    })

    r.HandleFunc("/hello", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>Hello from Docker!\n</h1>")
    })

    r.HandleFunc("/hello/{name}", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        vars := mux.Vars(r)
        title := vars["name"]

        fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>Hello, %s!\n</h1>", title)
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
```

Comment: Try running the image without "detach" option (`-d` flag). Also, you don't need `-it` here. Just run `docker run -p 8080:8080 --name goserver goserver` to see logs and error messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're starting your image in detached (`-d`) mode - this is why you don't see error messages. There are few issues with the `Dockerfile`, it should be fixed with @andre answer, but most probably you forgot to rebuild the image and didn't see the effect.

I'm submitting this answer to suggest some improvements of your `Dockerfile`:

```
# first stage - builds the binary from sources
FROM golang:1.12.14-alpine3.10 as build

# using build as current directory
WORKDIR /build

# Add the source code:
COPY main.go ./

# install build deps
RUN apk --update --no-cache add git

# downloading dependencies and
# building server binary
RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux && \
  go build -o server .

# second stage - using minimal image to run the server
FROM alpine:3.10

# using /app as current directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy server binary from `build` layer
COPY --from=build /build/server server

# binary to run
CMD "/app/server"

EXPOSE 8080
```

I've split your `Dockerfile` into two stages: build and run. Build stage is responsible for building the server binary, run stage is responsible for running it. See https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/ 
Then I combined multiple `RUN`s into single one: `go get github.com/gorilla/mux && go build -o server .` to avoid creating redundant layers. 
I fixed `WORKDIR`s and give them readable semantical names.

Don't forget to rebuild it with `docker build . -t goserver` and run it with

```sh
docker run -p 8080:8080 --name goserver goserver
```

If everything is fine, and you're ready to (and you need to) start in the detach mode, then add `-d` flag.

Also, you may want to check `Dockerfile` [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/).

Comment: Now that I am seeing the docker daemon's errors ( is that right) by using the -d flag I get this one error.  "template parsing error: open templates/home.html: no such file or directory"

Comment: @ReverendRonja it looks like your example in this question of `main.go` is differ from actual file. Make sure that you have same `main.go` in the project directory as in this question. I created example repository to reproduce your issue, you can follow steps from the `README` to build and run the server: https://github.com/g4s8/so59417246

Answer (score 1):

your `WORKDIR` is wrong, based on how you are setting your `CMD`

change your `WORKDIR` to `SRC_DIR` instead of `GOBIN` and it will work

You could also run `go install main.go` on your Dockerfile

`go install` will create the executable and move it to the bin folder

here is an example of a working Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1

ENV SRC_DIR=/go/src/
ENV GOBIN=/go/bin

WORKDIR $SRC_DIR

# Add the source code:
ADD . $SRC_DIR

RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux;
RUN go install main.go

WORKDIR $GOBIN
ENTRYPOINT ["./main"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

What was happening is: your `CMD` was failing because the `WORKDIR` was pointing to the bin folder.

A few side notes:

Don't do: `RUN cd`, as per: [Docker : RUN cd ... does not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891981/docker-run-cd-does-not-work-as-expected)

Comment: why am i still getting connection refused after making those changes?